# I want to make three of my jasmine tests to be done one after the other

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I want to make 3 of my jasmine tests synchronous. i.e. my verify token test should always be performed after the token generation test and before the reset password test. Can any one explain me how to do this?? It would be nicer if it is with the help of an example. Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async series` from [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to run the process one after another.